# Pasar data entre componentes no relacionados de forma dinamica en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

Tengo una aplicacion que tiene como un componente el navbar de la pagina y en otro componente el sidenavbar.
Quiero que un click en el componente navbar me dispare un evento en la sidenav.
El problema es que ambas se cargan a la vez, porque aparecen ni bien entras a la pagina. Con lo cual deberia ser esa parte de la sidenav, algo que cambie una vez que ya se termino de cargar.

Probe en hacerlo con un event emitter y funciona, pero tengo para eso que recargar la pagina, ya que no aplica los cambios en el momento porque cuando clickeo en el header y disparo el evento que hace que la sidenav cambie, la sidenav para ese momento ya se termino de cargar por supuesto con lo cual no le hace efecto visible hasta q no se recargue todo.

Me pasa lo mismo si lo hago mediante un servicio.

El problema en resumen es que si clickeo en un boton del header y quiero, por ejemplo, que con ese boton se cambie el color de fondo de la sidenav, se aplica pero no dinamicamente sino luego de relodear la pagina. Hay manera de que la sidenav escuche ese evento y actue en el momento, cambiando esa parte (en el caso del ejemplo su color de fondo) sin necesidad de recargar?

Gracias!!

Comment: Agrega tu codigo.

Comment: que codigo ramiro es una pregunta conceptual nomas

Comment: Imagino que necesatias una respuesta con codigo, diciendote llama a este método o este evento dentro tu método o evento. entonces ese código se necesita para quien te explique, lo haga con código también. Fijate de hacer el recorrido que ofrece el sitio para poder realizar una pregunta mejor recibida.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres lograr es dar click en algún elemento ( Boton por ejemplo ), que esté situado en tu navbar, y que abra/cierre tu sidebar component, eso lo puedes lograr usando un Observable ubicado en tu sidebar component. De esta manera ese observable escuchará los eventos ( click en este caso ) sobre el botón de tu navbar, y de esta forma podrás hacer el toggle ( abrir/cerrar ) de tu sidebar.

Quedaría así:

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav>
    <button type="button" id="toggle-sidebar">Toogle Sidebar</button>
    <a href="#">Enlace 1</a>
    <a href="#">Enlace 2</a>
    <a href="#">Enlace 3</a>
</nav>
```

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public mostrarSidebar = false;
  private subscription = new Subscription();
  private trigger = 'toggle-sidebar'; // elemento disparador (botón) en navbar view template

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const element = document.getElementById(this.trigger);
    const clickEnNavbar = fromEvent(element, 'click');

    this.subscription = clickEnNavbar
      .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
        this.mostrarSidebar = !this.mostrarSidebar
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Saludos bro, espero te sirva!.